# How the aggregation and calculated members work as combined to produce output in SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I am creating a POC on the SSAS. Ultimate goal is to be able to perform any kind of the calculation either ad hoc calculation or pre calculated with good performance. Existing solutions is based on the SQL server but due to the performance issues with huge data facing issues.

I need some insight upon how the Cube works to give faster outputs. I have created date dimensions with hierarchy Year-> Semester-> Quarter -> Month -> Week -> Date. Several other dimensions are linked with the date dimension. My cube has almost 10 to 15 dimension which have several role playing dimensions.There are almost two to three dates in every fact table.

1. How the Cube aggregates the data based on the dimensions linked to the facts?
2. Does it internally creates all the combination of the dimension values and saves the fact aggregate data internally?
3. Here i have attached an MDX script which hase YTD,MTD,QTD Calculated Measures.[Measures].[Value] measure has to be added based on the function applied on the date dimension. Does SSAS internally sum up the [Measures].[Value] for various hierarchy of the date/Other dimension/s? What exactly SSAS does to provide the final value fast?
4. Our system has large number of the fields whose calculation depends on the value selected by the end user to the number has to be calculated at run time by aggregating some other measures. Does SSAS is fast to provide the Calcualted Member output by using the internally aggregated values generated during the cube processing?

   ```
    With Member [Measures].[YTDValue] as ([Measures].[Value],
    OpeningPeriod([Rundate].[Calendar].[Date],[Rundate].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent))
    Member [Measures].[QTDValue]
                           as ([Measures].[Value],OpeningPeriod([Rundate].[Calendar].[Date],[Rundate].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent.Parent))
    Member [Measures].[MTDValue]
                           as ([Measures].[Value],OpeningPeriod([Rundate].[Calendar].[Date],[Rundate].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent))

           SELECT 

                       {   
                           [Measures].[YTDValue],
                           [Measures].[QTDValue],
                           [Measures].[MTDValue],
                       } on 0,

                       {   
                           [Rundate].[Calendar].[Date].Members
                       } ON 1

                       FROM  
                       (
                           select 
                           {
                               [Rundate].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-01-09T00:00:00]
                           } on 0 
                           from [Cube_Sample]
                       )
   ```

Comment: why do you not use the functions `YTD`, `MTD` and `QTD`?

Comment: @whytheq : I dont have to calculate the YTD,MTD and QTD values. They the Year start date ,Month start date,Quarter Start date values